# How to set the default font size in Windows 7 without scaling the rest?

Tags: windows-7, fonts

There is an option to "Make text *and other screen items* larger or smaller". How do I set **only the font size**, but leave the other screen items unchanged?

---

**Motivation** I have a netbook, the screen is small and there is no space to scale up non-font elements or else they go off-screen.

On the other hand, the fonts are too small to be easily read.

My priorities are:

- The font size of the *start menu*
- A system-wide setting, if possible
- A list of registry entries would be the best :)

I looked for the other answers, but I think they would upscale everything, not just the fonts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to...
`Control Panel` > `Personalization` > `Window Color` > `Advanced appearance settings...`
...or...
Right-click the desktop, select `Personalize`, and continue with the above sequence.

[image]

From here, you can change the system-wide font size (on its own) for various things. Changing the **Icon** font size is the one that affects the Start Menu text.

Comment: All the elements in the *"Font"* line was dimmed out on a Windows 7 system I tried this on (and thus could not be changed). Are there some preconditions for this to work?

Comment: For each "_Item:_" selection, only the relevant elements are active. As you select different items, can you confirm that the active elements change as expected? Or are all elements in the bottom row always disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem also. I believe you have to change from Aero to Basic windows in order for this the font to become visible and changeable.